# PHP $_ENV['HOSTNAME'] no longer returns a value

Tags: php

Hi when I echo $_ENV['HOSTNAME'] from a PHP script it no longer works, it used to (I think my server hosting company has changed a setting but I cant think what)

When I run hostname from the command line I get the proper (expected) hostname, also when I do

php -r 'echo $_ENV["HOSTNAME"];'

I get the proper (expected) hostname as well.

Any ideas? Servers are running CentOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The availability of the ENV array indeed depends on the webserver configuration. Inspect the SERVER array or try using `gethostname()` instead.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. This is code that has worked and hasn't changed, it was happily using $_ENV for a while, I understand that the variables_order can affect this but I dont understand why the SERVER array would now have this value, how/where would this be defined on the server itself?

Comment: SERVER won't have HOSTNAME, as far as I can tell. I was suggesting that perhaps another variable, like HTTP_HOST, could be used instead. See this question: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780866/why-is-my-env-empty. Also, this list may come in handy: http://www.php-developer.org/wp-content/uploads/scripts/PHP-Server-Array-Variables.php

Comment: Hi, that would mean I need to change my code, I'm more interested in finding out what change would have caused this, if its in apache, php etc?

Comment: I'd say `E` is probably missing from `variables_order` in the appropriate `php.ini`. Is that right?

Comment: nah E is the first one EGPCS we dont have SERVER['HOSTNAME'] set either and nothing in the get, post and cookies :(